# Awk solution for table formatting

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, awk

There is a table in the below format. Is it possible to have an AWK script to format the table in such a way it excludes columns which contain only the number "1"?

```
ST L1 L2 L3 L4 L5
ST2 1 1 1 1 1
ST2 1 0 1 0 1
ST3 1 0 1 0 1
ST3 0 0 1 1 1
ST4 1 0 1 0 1
ST5 1 0 1 0 1
ST6 1 0 1 0 1
ST7 0 0 1 1 1
ST8 0 0 1 0 1
ST9 1 0 1 0 1
```

Output should be as below:

```
ST L1 L2 L4
ST2 1 1 1
ST2 1 0 0
ST3 1 0 0
ST3 0 0 1
ST4 1 0 0
ST5 1 0 0
ST6 1 0 0
ST7 0 0 1
ST8 0 0 0
ST9 1 0 0
```

I can sort of understand the logic in how a column should be printed, as in whatever the value of NR in the end block, if that is equal to the variable which should be incremented each time 1 is found, for a given column (except header NR==1 and column $1), print the column. My trouble lies in actually trying to print the columns in the end block, as I am trying to use arrays and I am still learning AWK and array's. I am sure there is some clever way out there of doing this though without even using arrays and simply changing the way AWK looks at the data.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, working good! Now just to wrap my head round the code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if (NR > 1) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if ($i != 1) {
                nonOnes[i]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    ofs=""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (i in nonOnes) {
            printf "%s%s", ofs, $i
            ofs=OFS
        }
    }
    print ""
}
' file file
ST L1 L2 L4
ST2 1 1 1
ST2 1 0 0
ST3 1 0 0
ST3 0 0 1
ST4 1 0 0
ST5 1 0 0
ST6 1 0 0
ST7 0 0 1
ST8 0 0 0
ST9 1 0 0
```

If you don't want to list the same file twice on the command line you can tweak to add this BEGIN section:

```
BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
```

Comment: Hi Ed - How would this be code be written to work on just the one file instead of multiple files? Or is it relying on there being multiple files for it to work?

Comment: It does just work on 1 file. You just pass the same file name twice. First time it parses the file it figures out what columns are not all-ones, next it prints the columns that aren't all-ones. If you'd rather not pass the same file name twice to the script, see the edit I just made at the bottom of my post to add a BEGIN section that duplicates the file name arg.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
    {
        # store current line
        line[FNR] = $0

        if (FNR > 1) # skip header
        {
            # select columns
            for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++)
            {
                if ($i != 1) selected[i] = 1
            }
        }
    }

END {
        for (li = 1 ; li <= FNR ; li++)
        {
            # parse current line
            $0 = line[li]

            # pick selected fields
            for (i = j = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++)
            {
                if (selected[i]) $(j++) = $i
            }

            # trim record to selection
            NF = j-1
            print
        }
    }
```

After Ed Morton's remarks:

- changed the `l` to something less ambiguous
- printf is a statement indeed, but adding parentheses won't hurt either, or would it?
- agreed for `print ""` being better than `printf "\n"`
- semicolons are optional but won't hurt. I feel more comfortable with something that looks like C
- NR was a typo that went unnoticed (since it produced the expected output by pure luck). I meant NF.
- changed the logic so that no trailing blanks are added (and printf is not used anymore)

After a second batch of remarks:

- changed output record generation, to avoid extraneous separators.

Thanks a lot for the proofreading. It's been nearly 15 years since I last did some serious hawk programming, and the rust has sadly set in.

Comment: never use the the letter l (el) as a variable as it looks far too much like the number 1 (one). printf is a builtin, not a function, so the parens aren't doing what it looks like. `print ""` isthe normal way to print the ORS so you don't need to hard-code it. The spurious trailing semi-colons are undesirable. Use of FNR sometimes and NR others is confusing. The printf "%s " will add trailing blank chars to every output line. You're using NR instead of NF in your last print block.

Comment: You can add parens around any expression, same as in C (hence `return(foo)` and `sizeof(bar)`) and it shouldn't cause breakage, it just makes people reading your code wonder what the purpose is of doing so. Same with adding unnecessary `;`s at the end of statements. I'd expect your new solution to fail since you're recompiling $0 every time you hit a $i that you want to skip so the values of the field numbers are different afterwards than what you originally read in. Or it might just leave additional blanks between fields.

Comment: I agree with your comments about the style. I spent far more time using C/C++ than awk, so I simply carried over the habits. However, I don't think setting $i to "" will recompile $0. $0 will be recompiled if you assign $0 a new value or add fields, not if you change the value of an existing one. That's what the doc says, and what experience told me (using gawk at least). Setting $i to "" may indeed leave several blanks between output fields, but the OP did not specifically request the result to have only one separator between each column, so that seems acceptable to me.

Comment: Setting $i to any value DOES cause $0 to be recompiled (try `echo "a b c" | awk -v OFS=',' '{$2=""; print}'`), but it looks like it still leaves an empty field rather than collapsing the FSs on either side of it even if that would be the behavior on an initial read of that record so yes, it's just additional spaces between fields (and in this case at the end of the line) that you'd end up with. Usually that's undesirable but YMMV I suppose.

Comment: You're right again. $0 is indeed synthetized from the $i records, but what I meant was, NF does not change (setting $i to "" does not destroy $i, unless you do something like $0 = $0 afterwards to force a re-parsing of the record). Good point about the separators at end of line, though. That finally convinced me to change my code :). Thanks for your patience and helpfulness, and I bow to your mastery of awk.

Comment: btw. the "$0 = $0" hack does not seem to work on every implementation. I remember using it in the 90's, but the current gawk version does not seem to recompile $0 in that case. Not a nice way of doing things anyway, IMHO.